# Two computers can't connect to the same VPN simultaneously

Tags: vpn, lan

My colleague and I are on the same local network, trying to connect to our office headquarter's VPN. Any of us can connect without trouble, but when we try together, the second computer fails to connect.

Our configs are 13.04 and 13.10. My colleague tried with a Fedora distro, which produced the same error.

When we try with Windows PC or Android smartphone, everything works fine.

Any help is welcome.

---

**edit:**

More details:

We both use the native VPN that we activate via the *VPN Connections* menu in the network menu, top right corner of the default Unity desktop.

We both have different logins/keys to connect.

Answer (score 0):

> Any of us can connect without trouble

So both of your side works.

> but when we try together, the second computer fails to connect.

That is a common thing when using VPN. At our office regardless of who it is and what operating system we have the following happen:

- 1 client wants us to use Cisco VPN and only ONE person can log in. The 2nd one kills the connection of the 1st one. Very annoying since we needed to talk to all at our office to see if the VPN was free. This later got changed by our client to the 2nd one (and others) not being able to log in at all until the 1st one exits.
- 1 client wants us to use Cisco VPN and we can all log in at the same times.
- 1 client wants us to use Citrix VPN with security key and we can all log in at the same time with 1 key each (the same key can not be used 2 times at the same time).

> office headquarter

They probably need to fix this for you. It is probably a configuration in the VPN that prevents the 2nd one from logging in.

A more specific answer probably relies on the type/brand of VPN used.

Comment: I put more infos in the question, so you can complete your answer.